# ValueError when using scikit-learn train_test_split function in PySpark Pandas UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

I want to create a `pandas udf` function for Pyspark in which I am using the scikit-learn `train_test_split` function and returning a dataframe.

And I have a dataframe like this:
[image]
But in my dataframe, there is no id column. So I have added id column in dataframe

This is what I have done.

```
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def load_dataset(df):
    X = df[X_columns]
    y = df[y_columns]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
    
    df_sample_0 = pd.concat([y_test, X_test], axis=1)
 
    return df_sample_0
```

And this is how I am applying groupby:

```
sample_df = final_df_spark.groupby("id").apply(load_dataset)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Some groups in the grouped dataframe contains only 1 row. You have to take care of these groups which cannot be split into test/train data.

Comment: Can you explain me by example? @mck

Comment: Say you have a dataframe with a column id, `1, 1, 2`. You group by id, and apply your pandas UDF. How are you gonna do a test/train split on id=2?

Comment: But actually the column id of each row is unique in my dataframe.

Comment: Then if you group by id, each grouped dataframe will contain 1 row. How are you going to split each group of 1 row?

Comment: This is confusion for me, so according to you how can i do this?

Comment: It is impossible. You need to rethink what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Suppose if I have a CSV file and I want to add id column in CSV  to group by for this thing ,how do i create that id column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced `id` column to `Age` column.

```
sample_df = final_df_spark.groupby("Age").apply(load_dataset)
```